# Digital input via USB to PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, serial-port, powerpoint

I am interested in reading a single digital input (a switch. 0/5v) as a variable in PowerPoint vba. My only port is USB. I also have an rs232 to USB converter.
Any ideas? Links?
Thanks.

Comment: A switch is not going to generate RS-232 serial data, i.e. a framed character with start and stop bits.  If you have both positive and negative voltages, then one of the handshake lines could be used.  But this is not really a programming question.

Comment: Thank you sawdust, You are obviously correct in pointing out that a switch is not going to generate rs232 data. As I am not going to use a proper plc with designated digital inputs, my idea was to use one of the rs232 lines or even one of the usb data pins to carry the information about the status of my single switch. I guess there is a way to map the binary status of each pin by means of software. I have no idea whether this is a straightforward task or not.

Comment: The *"USB data pins"* use differential signals, so you cannot use just *"one of"* them.  And the USB signal/protocol is even more complicated than RS-232 framing.  There are modules such as USB-GPIO interfaces, which can easily deal with a switch.  *"I guess there is a way to map the binary status of each pin by means of software."* -- That requires a microcontroller, which is embedded in such a USB-GPIO module.  Seems like you severely underestimate what USB is.  As I already wrote, a RS-232 handshake line requires both positive and negative voltages.

Comment: No disrespect to the complexity of any protocol, my assumption was that at any given time the physical status of any usb pin is either a logical 1 or a logical 0, and the idea was to read that line which comes from the "terminal". Anyway, using one of the s-232 handshake lines seems to be a viable idea, only I do not know how to do that in VBA. Any suggested leads?

Comment: *"my assumption was that at any given time the physical status of any usb pin is either a logical 1 or a logical 0"* -- Apparently you persist in making assumptions rather than learn.  USB 2.0 is half-duplex and uses differential signals.  Sampling a data line is going to get you random information of USB packets of unknown polarity.

Comment: I had realized my wrong assumption, hence the past tense. What about rs-232?